# How to Create Three Types of Cylinder with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create three different types of cylinder like this below:

[image: cylinder]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possibility that works with the Ti*k*Z library `perspective` to set the 3d view. The rest consists of drawing a lot of arcs and a couple of lines. Something like this:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,isometric view,rotate around z=315,yscale=0.5]
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{atan(4/3)}
\def\h{3} % height
% first cylinder
\fill[cyan!30] (0,0) circle (2);
\draw[dashed] (-2,0) arc (180:0:2);
\draw (-2,0,\h) --++ (0,0,-\h) arc (180:360:2) --++ (0,0,\h);
\draw (0,0,\h) circle (2);
\node at (0,0) {$A$};
% second cylinder
\begin{scope}[shift={(6,0)}]
\fill[cyan!30,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (2) (0,0) circle (1);
\draw[dashed] (-2,0) arc (180:0:2);
\draw         (-2,0,\h) --++ (0,0,-\h) arc (180:360:2) --++ (0,0,\h);
\foreach\i in {1,2}
  \draw       (0,0,\h) circle (\i);
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (1);
\foreach\i in {-1,1}
  \draw[dashed] (\i,0,0) -- (\i,0,\h);
\node at (-1.5,0) {$A$};
\end{scope}
% third cylinder
\begin{scope}[shift={(12,0)}]
\fill[cyan!30] (\a:2) arc (\a:360-\a:2) arc (180-\a:90:3) arc (-90:90:1) arc (270:180+\a:3);
\draw[dashed]  (-2,0) arc (180:\a:2) arc (180+\a:270:3) arc (90:0:1);
\draw          (-2,0,\h) --++ (0,0,-\h) arc (180:360-\a:2) arc (180-\a:90:3) arc (-90:0:1) --++ (0,0,\h);
\draw          (\a:2) + (0,0,\h) arc (\a:360-\a:2) arc (180-\a:90:3) arc (-90:90:1) arc (270:180+\a:3);
\node at (0,0) {$A$};
\end{scope}
% heights
\foreach\i in {2,8,16}
{
  \foreach\j in {0,\h}
    \draw[red] (\i,0,\j) -- (\i+1,0,\j);
  \draw[red,latex-latex] (\i+0.75,0,0) -- (\i+0.75,0,\h) node[midway,right] {$h$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Or, removing the option `yscale=0.5` and changing the height, `\def\h{2}`, you'll get a really isometric figure:
[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks for your help, sorry I show no effort just asking for help on this question.. Next time I will have MWE.